# Excel Formula to incorporate: >0 = update, <0 don't update

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

My current output for cell B3 is `=IF(C3="Sell",A3,IF(C3="Buy",A3,B2))`

But what i want it to do is if its not "Sell" or "Buy" then rather than just simply = B2, i want it to have a look at cell D3 and if D3 is **greater than zero** then = A3 but if its **less than zero** then = B2.

I have no idea how to to incorporate that many IFs, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not really sure why it says not to saying thank you, but thank you both for your answers, both worked perfectly. I am sure i will have loads more questions to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, IF/ELSE statements are annoyingly difficult in Excel.  Since C3=="Sell" and C3=="Buy" return the same thing, you should incorporate an OR statement.

You still need a nested IF to handle the compare to B2, but the second part is easy.

> IF(OR(C3="Sell", C3="Buy"), A3, IF(D3>0, A3, B2))

Note:  This will also return B2 if D3 == 0

Comment: Surely the `D3>0` test can be folded into the `OR` statment, like so: `IF(OR(C3="Sell", C3="Buy", D3>0), A3, B2)` - although, OP has not specified what to do if D3 **=** 0

Comment: The OR() statement does not have a execution portion.  It merely returns a Boolean value (TRUE or FALSE) based on the test inside.